# Calling a SuperClass's DataSource?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am working on a Simple Slot Machine. I Sub-Classed from UIPickerView. The PickerView DataSource I don't need to define in my controller, because it will always be 5. Can I define it in my subclass like so?

```
@interface SlotMachineView : UIPickerView <UIPickerViewDataSource> {
```

}

@end

```
#import "SlotMachineView.h"

@implementation SlotMachineView

- (id)init{

if ((self = [super init])) {
    super.dataSource = self;
}

return self;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{

return 5;
}


- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

return 5;
}

- (void)dealloc
{ 
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can also just write `self.dataSource = self`, because `super` and `self` are the same object*. Remember, your object is just as much an instance of its superclass as it is an instance of the class it's declared as. It has all the same properties and responds to all the same messages.

<sub>*The only difference between `super` and `self` is that `super` skips over methods defined in the current class.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Everything is working know. I guess my problem was interacting with interface builder, because I just called addSubview and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Thats the whole point behind protocols.